# ROS2 (no map recieved) SLAM with lidar

Tags: ros2, rviz, slam, lidar, rplidar

i have lidar( X2L 2D ydlidar /RPlidar A1) in hand and want to build a map with it as a first step of my project.

so i used the ROS2 driver for the ydlidar to get the scan topic and slam toolbox to build the map.

i could get the output of the lidar but i could not get the map as in the figure below [image]

here is some more information

- i changed the following params in the mapper_params_online_async.yaml

  ```
    odom_frame: base_link
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_link
    scan_topic: /scan
    use_map_saver: true
    mode:mapping #localization
    #map_file_name: /home/dev/dev_ws/my_map_serial
    #map_start_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    #map_start_at_dock: true
  ```
- also i got the following msg from the toolbox

[async_slam_toolbox_node-1] [INFO] [1706389021.867733094] [slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_frame' at time 1706389021.640 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'.

- here is some more infos
  [image]

[image]

best regards

Comment: Can you show you tf tree? After driving the robot around for a few seconds run
ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames.py
And share screenshot of the frames.pdf that it downloads.